# Eclipse listens on port 42540 (?)

Tags: eclipse, port, malware, listen

I just appalledly realized my Eclipse IDE listens on port 42540. During the past weeks I installed some more or less useful plug-ins (and removed some of them). Maybe one of them listens on this port, but I don't think/hope so. Currently, the following plug-ins are installed:

- Eclipse Color
  Theme    0.11.0.201104281646
  com.github.eclipsecolortheme.feature.feature.group
- Eclipse IDE for Javascript
  Developers   1.3.2.20110218-0812 epp.package.javascript
- FontsFeature 1.0.4   FontsFeature.feature.group
- PyDev for
  Eclipse  2.0.0.2011040403    org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group
- Pydev Mylyn
  Integration  0.3.0   org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group

Eclipse does not answer HTTP requests on port 42540.
Is listening on port 42540 an intended behavior? How can I stop Eclipse listening on this port?

Sorry for being paranoid.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that it is the built-in Jetty instance (a Webserver) for the Eclipse help system, even if it doesn't answer HTTP requests from a normal webbrowser.

Comment: On my machine, the help server was not running until I accessed help for the first time.  At that point it opened port 45953 (random), and I can see it by pointing a browser at http://localhost:45953/help/index.jsp.  This is the only port my eclipse is listening to, I am running Eclipse SDK + CDT + EGit + SVN

Comment: I tried http://localhost:42540/help/index.jsp but it doesn't respond (the listening port is still there). Maybe it has something to do with the Eclipse package which is "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers." Why doesn't it listen on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Any idea? Today, eclipse listens on port 40498. I'm still worried :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem / concern. The port went away after I uninstalled a plugin we have in common - PyDev for Eclipse.

I reinstalled PyDev *without* PyDev Mylyn Integration. Eclipse is still not listening on a random high-numbered port. So it seems the Mylyn integration portion of PyDev is responsible for the open port.